# How to go to fragment from notification before app is first time launched?

Tags: android, android-fragments, push-notification

Helo, I am building app with notifications. I want to, when user clicks on notification, to send him to Fragment1. And that is okay in almost all cases , except one.My problem is when app is only installed(never launched) and notifications comes, than user is not send to the Fragment1, then he is sent to the MainActivity...What should I do?

this is myFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class myFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseMsgService";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d(TAG, "From " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Body " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("Msg", "Poruka je stigla");
}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
    Intent intent=new Intent(myFirebaseMessagingService.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("action", "goToFragment1");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(logo)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setContentTitle("Naslov")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());



}
```

and this is my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button dugme, dugme2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("onCreate", "ONCREATE");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("action");
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (msg != null) {
        if (msg.equals("goToFragment1")) {
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);
            Log.d("FragmentTransaction", "Fragment je promenjen u onCreate!");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            Log.d("Create", "Kraj onCreatea");
        }
    }

    dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme1);
    dugme2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (view == dugme) {
                fragment = new Fragment1();
            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });


    dugme2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("android");
            Log.d("Log", "Uspesno ste se pretplatili");
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.d("onNewIntent", "NewIntent");
    handleIntentExtra(intent);
}

private void handleIntentExtra(Intent intent) {
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("action");
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (msg != null) {
        if (msg.equals("goToFragment1")) {
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Does the Fragment not show up?

Comment: It loads just MainActivity, not the Fragment1.When I click on notification, it sends me on the first page on MainActivity, not to the Fragment1 (where I want to go).

Answer (score 0):

When you first run the app it will go to your onCreate method in MainActivity. There you have these two lines of code 
Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);

Try this:
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);

And I would suggest adding the fragment to the back stack.

Comment: Should I delete these 2 lines and write this yours or just to write your code below these 2 lines?

Comment: Replace this line of code fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);  with this one fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);

Comment: Okay, just another question: How to add fragment to back stack?

Comment: fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myFragment, fragment1).addToBackStack("Fragment1.TAG"); You should read a bit about the fragment lifecycle and backstack.

Comment: I have replaced my code with yours, but still is the same...I didn't write this part with back stack because i don't understand this TAG in ("Fragment1.TAG")

Comment: "Fragment1.TAG" is just a String used to identify your fragment in the Backstack in case you need it later. You can put any String there.

Comment: I tried all this, but again I go on MainActivity, not to the Fragment1..:(

Comment: I read somewhere that I must put launch mode in manifest, what do you think?